# How to find next position of a value and count of values between them in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'Decimal' : [3,1,5,1,5,2,3,3,7,2]})
df
```

[image]

I need to create a new column "nextPosition" which has values like

```
nextPosition = [5,1,1,-1,-1,3,0,-1,-1,-1]
```

where the values are derived from column 'Decimal' values, example

5 - in column 'Decimal' 1st row value 3 appears again after 5 values

1 - in column 'Decimal' 2nd row value 1 appears again after 1 value

1 - in column 'Decimal' 3rd row value 5 appears again after 1 value

-1 - in column 'Decimal' 4th row value 1 doesn't appear again, so -1

and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
df['nextPosition'] = df.groupby('Decimal', sort=False)['Position'].diff(-1).abs().sub(1).fillna(-1)

print(df)
```

```
   Position  Decimal  nextPosition
0         1        3           5.0
1         2        1           1.0
2         3        5           1.0
3         4        1          -1.0
4         5        5          -1.0
5         6        2           3.0
6         7        3           0.0
7         8        3          -1.0
8         9        7          -1.0
9        10        2          -1.0
```